# MySQL is always populated with NULL Values, what am I missing (Play 1.2 framework)?

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-1.x

**The view.html looks like this, what am I missing because of which the tables are populated with null values ?**

```
                <form class="form-inline form-fields" action="SubmitArticle" method="POST">

                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group success">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input01"><a>Author Name</a></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01" name="${article?.author}">
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-actions">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-large span2" type="submit" name="commit"> Submit </button>
                    </div>      




                    <div class="control-group right-area success">
                    <label class="control-label" for="input01"><a>Abstract</a></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                    <textarea id="textarea" class="input-xlarge" rows="3" style="width: 498px; height: 283px;" name="${article?.abstract}"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>




                </fieldset>

           </form>
```

**and the action in my controller looks like this:**

```
 public static void SubmitArticle(String article_name, User author, String         article_abstract) {

        Article article = new Article(article_name, author, article_abstract);
        article.save();
              }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, please post more. Show us how you handle the POST-request..

Comment: I believe this html line takes care of POST-request:                                                     <form class="form-inline form-fields" action="SubmitArticle" method="POST">

Comment: Have you've read this? http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/guide2

Comment: Oh.. my Model is called Article, and it has a method with this signature:                                             Article(String article_name, Object author, String article_abstract)

Comment: what's wrong with my code ? I have followed Playframework documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="input01" name="${article?.author}">
```

The name field is incorrect, the name field should be the same as the attribute it will be mapped to in your object. What you have set as `${article?.author}` should be value. Read a little more on Form to Object binding.

Comment: Yeah.. it works, do you have any good links on form binding etc. I didn't really find documentation on Play! Framework web site elaborate enough

Comment: read this - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#overview, and remember that the name element of a form, is the name of the field you are binding to.